# jpos : Build failed suddenly for no reason

Tags: jpos

I was building jpos application which was all good for all these days.

I use to run the below command to build and both were working fine.

gradlew.bat assemble -x signArchives installApp  or

gradlew.bat assemble -x signArchives install

But suddenly the build failed with below message ,I haven't changed anything.
have no clue why it would fail. please help how can i get my build successful.

```
> Task :jpos:processResources FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':jpos:processResources' because:
  Caching has not been enabled for the task
Task ':jpos:processResources' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
:jpos:processResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.106 secs.

> Task :qnode:javadoc
Build cache key for task ':qnode:javadoc' is 1b25edb3d0d8c177cce7379d93017208
Task ':qnode:javadoc' is not up-to-date because:
  Input property 'classpath' file C:\Users\e064070\IdeaProjects\jPOS\qnode\build\resources\main\org\jpos\qnode\buildinfo.prop
erties has changed.
Starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\javadoc.exe''. Working directory: C:\Users\e064070\IdeaProj
ects\jPOS\qnode Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\javadoc.exe @C:\Users\e064070\IdeaProjects\jPOS\qnode\build\t
mp\javadoc\javadoc.options
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\javadoc.exe''
Packing task ':qnode:javadoc'
:qnode:javadoc (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 9.925 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Hi Abrar, I don't know why that could be happening, but I wonder why are you trying to build jpos in the first place instead of just using it as a compiled library.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz I created a custom channel ,so tried to build jpos

Comment: When you create a custom channel, you typically put the channel in your own codebase, and use jPOS as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that task `signArchives` is not present in project.

You just need to remove the `-x signArchives` part.

But that said, you don't need to manually compile jPOS unless you are trying to modify it.

To create a custom channel you also don't need (and don't want) to do it inside the jPOS project, you can (and should) do it in your own project.

Comment: thanks .sure will be creating my own  project as I am not trying to modify anything in jpos other than creating configs or creating packages or channels